# is it possible to create an instance for an existing model in sails js as below?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

```
var userModel = new User();
userModel.email = req.body.email;
userModel.password = req.body.password;
userModel.save(function(err, user) {
    .........
}
```

> Actually i have a model named 'User' and i have to create instance for that to store its attributes temporarily and save it as encapsulated object. But it's showing error from my controller like following..

```
throw message;      
      ^
    TypeError: object is not a function
```

> Is it possible to create like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the model.create() function. [Documentation Wateline Model.Create](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/models/create.html)